# Custom bean validation not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

In my Student class I have many fields which I am storing in the database and I also have one field to store photo( for that I am using MultiPartFile datatype) and I am validating this field using custom validation.

Below is code for validation

```
@Component
public class PhotoValidator implements Validator{

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Student.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Student student=(Student)target;

        if(student.getStudentPhoto()!=null){
            if(student.getStudentPhoto().getSize()==0){
                errors.rejectValue("file", "missing.file");
            }
        }
        if(!student.getStudentPhoto().getOriginalFilename().endsWith(".jpg")){
            errors.rejectValue("file", "invalid.file");
        }
    }

}
```

In the controller I am implementing it like this

```
    @InitBinder

protected void initBinderStudent(WebDataBinder binder) {        binder.setValidator(photoValidator);
    }
```

My Student Model is :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student extends UrlEntity {

    @Transient
    MultipartFile studentPhoto;

    @Column(name = "COURSE_TYPE", nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Course Type: Course Type can not be left blank")
    private in.jmi.constants.CourseType courseType;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_USER")
    @Valid
    private User user;
```

This custom validation of photo is not working and it also mess up the other annotation based validation that I am having here.

I have checked many posts in stackoverflow but couldn't find any relation to this particular problem.

Note:-If I remove the validation code from controller the code works just fine doing all the validations it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing approaches in your example. You are not showing the imports in your code example, but the `PhotoValidator` class does not implement a Bean Validation constraints. It might be some Spring/JSF specific validator!?

To implement a Bean Validation constraint, you need to define a constraint annotation and at least one implementing `ConstraintValidator`. This is all described in [Creating custom constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints). There are plenty of examples out there how to write a custom constraint.

Comment: I have implemented the above code separately and it runs, here is the website from where I have learned this http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-file-upload-example-using-commons-fileupload/ , The problem is when I implement the same in my application it does not run. ==>What I want to achieve is validate for .jpg and empty files that's it.